# How do I Locate and click google map markers using selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I tried to search same question but answer was not as expected and i am not allowed to comment, Hence creating separate question.

So, In my project we are using Google map on one of the Page where I am getting multiple Locations as Google map Marker but when I am trying to Inspect those marker using xpath, Css,Id etc.
It doesn't give any element.
Please suggest How can I find such element using Jquery,xpath,css anyways?

I even tried using selenium IDE to get the location but it is giving same xpath for all location markers.

*Please do not suggest below code as we are not using image as link to marker*
Note: we are assigning dynamic Id to each of the marker still not able to find it.

```
 // goes to GMaps page and searches for "Washington" driver.get("https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Washington"); // clicks the only marker on the page driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[src*='markerTransparent.png']")).click();
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the google doc, You can **Set optimized : false** to the markers.

It will allow to locate/select the individual marker and can be inspected as below,
using xpath as usual e.g. "//div[@title='Site 1']" this will select all the markers with same title and then using index e.g "//div[@title='Site 1'][1]". 
You can then get your marker and perform the webdriver action as any webelement.